# how to use local storage in a proper way

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, localserver

i'm creating a form of inscription and i want to get info from a first page to show in a second one. I've tried to use local storage, but it doesn't work.

I've tried to test in the same page, which works, but when i try it with the localstorage, it doesn't work, and when i click on submit it reloads the page and nothing happens

Here is the code for the first page:

```
function rform()
{
    document.getElemeentByName('insc').reset;
}

function client()
{
    var sexe=document.getElemeentByName('gender');

    var userT=document.getElementById('choice').selectedIndex;
    var name = document.getEelementById('name').value;
    localStorage.setItem('name',name)

    if (userT[1] || userT[2] &&sexe[0].checked )
    {
        var choice = document.getElementById('choice').value;
        localStorage.setItem('choice',choice)
    else
    {

        var res = document.getElementById('choice').value + 'e';
        localStorage.setItem('choice',choice)
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the second page:

```
<span id="result"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= 'welcome ' 
        +localStorage.getItem('name')+ ' you are ' 
        +localStorage.getItem('choice');
</script>`
```

I get nothing in the second page, but expect to get a welcome message with the name and the user type

Comment: First of all you have a syntax error where the if statement is never closed.

Comment: It's not `getElemeentByName`. It should be `getElementsByName`

Comment: Your code is really a not understandable. Please edit it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
var choice = document.getElementById('choice').value;
localStorage.setItem('choice','choice')
```

This isn't setting the value of `Choice` into localStorage, this is simple setting the value of localStorage named `Choice`  to the string `"Choice"`.

Should be;

```
var choice = document.getElementById('choice').value;
localStorage.setItem('choice',choice);
```